# Documentation for migrating policies from stable-baselines to stable-baselines3

Tags: python, migration, stable-baselines

I'm working on updating a project I found (https://github.com/davidADSP/SIMPLE) to use stable-baselines3. I found the official migration guide: https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/migration.html#policies, but it seems to lack quite a bit of information. For example, the expected parameters for stable_baselines3.common.policies.BasePolicy seem to have changed significantly but I can't locate any information on how the new parameter relate to the old ones or what the equivalents in stable-baselines3 would be.

Has anyone successfully managed this migration with an existing code base? Is there some additional information somewhere I'm just not seeing?